# VSCode keybinding - pass user input into dialogue

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I want to to pass user input as an arg into the dialogue of a command in `keybinding.json`.
To bypass manual interaction.

For this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) example, I want to pass the value `HTML.html` and press enter automatically into the following dialogue by the defined shortcut `alt+m`.

[image]

I'm tried following example, but that didn't work:
`keybindings.json`

```json
    {
        "key": "alt+m",
        "command": "templates.newFileFromTemplate",
        "args": "HTML.html\n"
    }
```

Comment: related: [Is there a keyboard shortcut command for typing specified text into input boxes (not the editor) in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75954250/11107541)